# How to use parameters in query in several places?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using java `PreparedStatement` to set two parameters in a query begin time and end time. But in my query, I need to use it in two places. Can I make some query variables or make my request shorter?

```
SELECT * FROM publicutilities.orders
WHERE (works_begin between '2019-05-26 09:00:00' and '2019-05-26 14:00:00' OR works_end between '2019-05-26 09:00:00' and '2019-05-26 14:00:00')
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM publicutilities.orders
VARIABLE begin_time = ?
VARIABLE end_time = ?
WHERE (works_begin between begin_time and end_time OR works_end between begin_time and end_time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-variables/

I think your SQL query should look like:

```
SET @begin_time := '2013-01-17 00:00:00';
SET @end_time := '2013-01-17 00:00:00'; 
SELECT * FROM publicutilities.orders
WHERE (works_begin between @begin_time and @end_time OR works_end between @begin_time and @end_time)
```

I tried it on my mysql server and it works. Hope it does on yours too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SET @var_name := <value>` to identify an alias in SQL.

Rewriting your code,

```
SET @begin_ts := '2019-05-26 09:00:00'
SET @end_ts := '2019-05-26 14:00:00'
ELECT * FROM publicutilities.orders
WHERE (works_begin between @ begin_ts and @ end_ts OR works_end between @begin_ts and @end_ts)
```